# Default property setting in JavaScript (as seen in Lodash source)

Tags: javascript, arguments, underscore.js, lodash

While looking up how [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) implements its [extend method](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) I noticed they chose an atypical syntax for their default argument assignment.

What I'm used to:

```
function doStuff(obj) {
    obj = obj || {};
}
```

How lodash does it:

```
function doStuff(obj) {
    obj || (obj = {});
}
```

Is there any particular advantage to this style?  I get that the second way avoids an unnecessary assignment operation but is there any other reason to do it the lodash way or is this just a micro-optimization that I shouldn't bother worrying about.

Comment: I would prefer the first one since your intentions are clearer, but that's mostly personal preference.

Comment: the 2nd pattern might be faster or safer since it doesn't re-assign `obj` unless it has to, also making it much better for impure functions where the simple re-assignment of a value can be a problem.

Comment: In my case I like so much the second way but it is up to you.  But If you are use a code quality tool (jslint, jshint) be sure that you have it with a properly configuration.

Comment: @dandavis Could you explain how it might be safter?  I don't quite follow how this way is a better alternative for impure functions, after all they both seem equally impure to me.  Speed-wise seems to be a wash: http://jsperf.com/lodash-default-props

Comment: after looking at it some more, the simple syntax seems ok, it's a generalization of this type of operation that might present a problem in impure functions. the saving grace on this simple example is that objects/mutables cannot be falsy (and of course that the re-assignment is local-only).  if you stay within those restrictions, it's fine. what you for sure don't want to do is something like `obj.sub || (obj.sub = {});` on the above, or just using the above without the `obj` formal parameter. my orig concern was re-assigning objects that might be aliased, but i guess those can't be false...

Comment: aside from that, i do like the 2nd one computationally, but it's harder to read. i don't like code that spontaneously executes where at a typical glace the reader wouldn't expect execution; it's easier for most to read if something "kicks off" the conditional, like an IF or ternary. but, lodash must be kept small, and readability is not the only criterion we judge code patterns by, so i don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final summation - seems to be a personal preference.